# Is there any restriction if you play a sound into OnColliderEnter2D() or am I missing something?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here's my code, it's so basic and I know the solution will be too, but I checked in reference and still didn't fix it, any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks!

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Passed : MonoBehaviour
{
    AudioSource audioData;

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void OnColliderEnter2D()
    {
        audioData = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        audioData.Play(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you playing?

Comment: Any error? What is the exact issue? Do you have Collider2D components on your objects? Do you have a `Rigidbody2D` on at least one object?

Answer (score 1):

Have you created in your scene a Game Object: Audio Source and attached the audio? Then you attach that Audio Source created with your audioData.

On the other hand, I would write the code like this:

```
void Start()
{
    audioData = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}
void OnColliderEnter2D()
{    
    audioData.Play();
}
```

Also make sure the collision is being detected.

Comment: Solved, thanks! For some reason it wasn't detecting the collision, so I did it with a trigger and it worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the script is attached to the object, and I suggest you put the audio clip you want to play in a variable, use `public AudioClip SomeClip`. Also make sure there is no other sounds conflicting with the sound you're playing. You should only use `AudioSource.Play()` for background music(or sounds) because `AudioSource.Play()` can only play one sound at a time, if you're looking to have multiple sounds playing at the same time use `AudioSource.PlayOneShot()` with this method you can have multiple sounds play at the same time. Also make sure the AudioSource has correct settings.

Answer (score 0):

to detect collision 2d you need to use:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    Debug.Log("OnCollisionEnter2D");
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).